# How can I "pretty print" comparisons between ruby hashes so a user can easily see the differences between them in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, diff

I have a version history feature in my rails app that records snapshots of active record models by saving the model's `as_json` representation at that moment to a database column.

The model data is relational, with several nested `has_many` associations that also need to be displayed to the user.

I'd now like to make an easy way for users to compare versions, similar to what you might find in Wordpress or Github. ([example image](https://nschoenmaker.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/compare_revisions.png))

I've found [this gem](https://github.com/samg/diffy) which works great, but it only accepts strings as inputs.

I can't guarantee what top-level and nested keys will be present in a given object.

So, I think what I'd like to do is:

1. Reconstitute the stored object as a Ruby hash (already done)
2. Print the stored version of the object as YAML, using newlines and tabs to make it understandable to the user
3. Feed that string into the diffy gem and compare it with the same for a different version.

Alternatively, I could display the model as HTML (easy) and somehow compare that HTML with the HTML (seemingly hard, no diffing gems seem to do this and figuring it out manually seems to be beyond my abilities).

Just printing out the hash's `to_yaml` representation produces an ugly YAML output without tabs or newlines, and it fails validation when I try to run it through YAML validators. Not sure why this is.

Example of the kind of data I'm working with. Notice the nested association data.

```
 {"id"=>6, "name"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy", "organisation_id"=>3, "description"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy will be committed to delivering inspirational learning opportunities that are fun, purposeful and challenging. We want our children not just to achieve, but to exceed expectations and attain the very best results they can academically, creatively and personally. Our pupils will take ownership of their learning, becoming highly aspirational and resilient learners who are able to make positive contributions to life in modern Britain.\r\nOur pupils will be at the heart of every decision we make and we will offer a safe, nurturing and creative learning environment, which will enable us to foster a passion for learning and curiosity in a happy and supported way.", "url"=>"http://www.abbeyviewprimaryacademy.org/home", "visible"=>true, "email"=>"office@avpa.school", "visible_from"=>nil, "visible_to"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.965Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-06T14:00:21.420Z", "discarded_at"=>nil, "approved"=>true, "notes_count"=>0, "ofsted_reference_number"=>nil, "old_ofsted_external_id"=>nil, "label_list"=>[], "taxonomies"=>[{"id"=>318, "name"=>"Education and learning", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.033Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.033Z", "parent_id"=>1, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>4}, {"id"=>319, "name"=>"Primary schools", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.108Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.108Z", "parent_id"=>318, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>0}, {"id"=>255, "name"=>"Communication and Interaction", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.793Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.793Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>3}, {"id"=>254, "name"=>"Hearing", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.766Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.766Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>2}, {"id"=>253, "name"=>"Social, Emotional and Mental Health Difficulties", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.728Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.728Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>1}, {"id"=>252, "name"=>"Autism", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.661Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.661Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>0}], "locations"=>[{"id"=>6, "name"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy", "description"=>nil, "latitude"=>"51.616709", "longitude"=>"-0.745362", "address_1"=>" Kennedy Avenue", "city"=>"High Wycombe", "state_province"=>"Buckinghamshire", "postal_code"=>"HP11 1BX", "country"=>"GB", "google_place_id"=>nil}], "contacts"=>[{"service_id"=>6, "id"=>6, "name"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy", "title"=>"", "visible"=>false}], "cost_options"=>[], "regular_schedules"=>[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`JSON.pretty_generate`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate):

```
hash = {"id"=>6, "name"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy", "organisation_id"=>3, "description"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy will be committed to delivering inspirational learning opportunities that are fun, purposeful and challenging. We want our children not just to achieve, but to exceed expectations and attain the very best results they can academically, creatively and personally. Our pupils will take ownership of their learning, becoming highly aspirational and resilient learners who are able to make positive contributions to life in modern Britain.\r\nOur pupils will be at the heart of every decision we make and we will offer a safe, nurturing and creative learning environment, which will enable us to foster a passion for learning and curiosity in a happy and supported way.", "url"=>"http://www.abbeyviewprimaryacademy.org/home", "visible"=>true, "email"=>"office@avpa.school", "visible_from"=>nil, "visible_to"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.965Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-06T14:00:21.420Z", "discarded_at"=>nil, "approved"=>true, "notes_count"=>0, "ofsted_reference_number"=>nil, "old_ofsted_external_id"=>nil, "label_list"=>[], "taxonomies"=>[{"id"=>318, "name"=>"Education and learning", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.033Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.033Z", "parent_id"=>1, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>4}, {"id"=>319, "name"=>"Primary schools", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.108Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:50:16.108Z", "parent_id"=>318, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>0}, {"id"=>255, "name"=>"Communication and Interaction", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.793Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.793Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>3}, {"id"=>254, "name"=>"Hearing", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.766Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.766Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>2}, {"id"=>253, "name"=>"Social, Emotional and Mental Health Difficulties", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.728Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.728Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>1}, {"id"=>252, "name"=>"Autism", "created_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.661Z", "updated_at"=>"2020-06-04T17:09:13.661Z", "parent_id"=>251, "locked"=>nil, "sort_order"=>0}], "locations"=>[{"id"=>6, "name"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy", "description"=>nil, "latitude"=>"51.616709", "longitude"=>"-0.745362", "address_1"=>" Kennedy Avenue", "city"=>"High Wycombe", "state_province"=>"Buckinghamshire", "postal_code"=>"HP11 1BX", "country"=>"GB", "google_place_id"=>nil}], "contacts"=>[{"service_id"=>6, "id"=>6, "name"=>"Abbey View Primary Academy", "title"=>"", "visible"=>false}], "cost_options"=>[], "regular_schedules"=>[]}

require 'json'

JSON.pretty_generate(hash)
#=> {
#     "id": 6,
#     "name": "Abbey View Primary Academy",
#     "organisation_id": 3,
#     "description": "Abbey View Primary Academy will be committed to delivering inspirational learning opportunities that are fun, purposeful and challenging. We want our children not just to achieve, but to exceed expectations and attain the very best results they can academically, creatively and personally. Our pupils will take ownership of their learning, becoming highly aspirational and resilient learners who are able to make positive contributions to life in modern Britain.\r\nOur pupils will be at the heart of every decision we make and we will offer a safe, nurturing and creative learning environment, which will enable us to foster a passion for learning and curiosity in a happy and supported way.",
#     "url": "http://www.abbeyviewprimaryacademy.org/home",
#     "visible": true,
#     "email": "office@avpa.school",
#     "visible_from": null,
#     "visible_to": null,
#     "created_at": "2020-06-04T17:09:13.965Z",
#     "updated_at": "2020-06-06T14:00:21.420Z",
#     "discarded_at": null,
#     "approved": true,
#     "notes_count": 0,
#     "ofsted_reference_number": null,
#     "old_ofsted_external_id": null,
#     "label_list": [
#   
#     ],
#     "taxonomies": [
#       {
#         "id": 318,
#         "name": "Education and learning",
#         "created_at": "2020-06-04T17:50:16.033Z",
#         "updated_at": "2020-06-04T17:50:16.033Z",
#         "parent_id": 1,
#         "locked": null,
#         "sort_order": 4
#       },
#       {
#         "id": 319,
#         "name": "Primary schools",
# ...
```